# Summation for computing distance with time?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I have a homework problem for Calc II that goes something like this:

A tortoise and a hare are in a 1500m race. The hare goes 1m in the first second, (999/1000)m in the second second, a (999/1000)^2  in the third second, and (999/1000)^(n-1) in the nth second. The tortoise goes 1/10 m in the first second, and (1/(9+n)m in the nth second. Who wins the race?
I understand that to compute the TOTAL distance traveled at any given second, you would do a summation of either of the sequences provided. To try and solve for how many seconds it would take the hare to travel the 1500m I came up with this:

1500 = 1(1-(999/1000))^n/(1-(999/1000)

using the formula for the sum of the nth term of a sequence. It seems to solve for n I would need to use logarithms, is there an easier way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

The hare never makes it to the end of the race:

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac{999}{1000}}=1000\;.$$

No matter how long he keeps running, he’ll never quite complete the first kilometre. The tortoise’s associated series, on the other hand, is

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{9+n}\;,$$

a tail of the harmonic series, so it’s divergent, and the tortoise will eventually finish the race and win.